# Probability of two people being selected for jury service

Tags: probability

I manage a team of 6 and during the past 6 months two of them have been selected for jury service.  [According to the BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-36140259), you have $35\%$ chance of being selected for jury service over the course of your life and the eligible ages for select are 18 to 75.  So that's a $35\%$ chance over $57$ years.

My question is, how would you calculate the following:

1. The probability of an $1$ person being selected for jury service on a
   monthly basis.
2. Following on from question 1, what is the probability of $2$ people being selected for jury service in a $6$ month period?

Hope the above is clear, and I look forward to hearing back from you

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean precisely with "on a montly basis"?
And is is possible to being selected multiple times?

Comment: I guess technically it's 58 years inclusive, right? I would also say as a hint, you are interested in the probability of at least 2 people being selected in 6 months. since you would also be surprised at 3 or 4...

Comment: -  In terms of "on a monthly basis" I just mean that during any given month, what are the chances that someone would be selected for jury service, given that there's a 35% chance of being selected over the time period that you are eligible

Comment: - It is also possible to be selected multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$57$ years equals $684$ months. So, if $m$ is the probability of being selected for jury service during some month, then the probability of never being asked for jury service over the course of your life is:

$$(1-m)^{684}=0.35$$

If you solve this for $m$, you get $x \approx 0.0015$, or about $0.15$%

Now, for b) you ask: what is the probability that $2$ people are selected for jury duty in a six month period? Assuming the selection of one person is independent from the selection of the other person, let's first calculate the probability that $1$ person gets selected once during a six month period, which is:

$$6 \cdot 0.0015 \cdot (1-0.0015)^5 \approx 0.0089$$

i.e. just a bit less than $1$%.   So, for this to happen to two people, it would be:

$$0.0089^2 \approx 0.00008$$

i.e. less probable than $1$ in $10,000$

OK, so you might say: "Ah! I knew it! How unlucky were we, to get hit with two selections! Woe us!"

Well, you may actually not be *as* unlucky as you think you were.

First of all, it could have been worse: those two people could have been selected more than once during that $6$ month period. So, it would probably be more fair to calculate the probability of two people getting selected once or more during that period. For each individual person this is:

$$1-(1-0.0015)^6 \approx 0.0090$$

so for two people it's:

$$0.0090^2 \approx 0.00008$$

OK, so not much difference there, but again: the chances of getting selected once or more are greater than getting selected exactly once ... *and* you and your team were on the 'lucky' side of that.

OK, but here is something more important:  your team has $6$ people, not $2$.  If you would have had $1000$ people on your team, then $2$ being selected would of course not have been shocking, but still: $2$ out of $6$ is quite a bit more likely than $2$ out of $2$, and that's what we have been calculating so far.

OK, so let's rephrase the question again: what is the chance of $2$ people out of $6$ being selected at least once during a $6$ month period? Well, that would be:

$${6 \choose 2} \cdot 0.009^2 \cdot (1-0.009)^4 \approx 0.0012$$

which is a little over $1$ in $1,000$ ... which is an order of magnitude different from the $1$ in $10,000$ we had earlier. Still 'unlucky' of course, but not *as* unlucky!

Moreover, once again, it could have been worse! You could have had more than $2$ people being selected. OK, so let's calculate the chances of $2$ or more people being selected, which is $1$ minus the chance of $0$ or $1$ being selected, which is:

$$1-(1-0.009)^6-{6 \choose 1} \cdot 0.009^1 \cdot (1-0.009)^5 \approx 0.0012$$

OK, so again, not much difference there, but still, you are on the 'lucky' side of this probability.

Finally, though, and I think most importantly: Exactly when were these two people being selected?  Somehow, I have the feeling that they were not selected in the same month, since if that would have been the case, you would have asked us: "Two people in the same month! What are the chances of that?!". Indeed, likewise I don't think the selections were two or three months apart; in fact, my guess is that the second one occurred about $5$ or $6$ months after the first one.

Also: let's go outside those $6$ months:  were there any selections during the $6$ months before that?  I doubt it, for if there was, you would have asked us the probability of getting $3$ (!) selections in a year.  My point is: you are presenting us with a small snapshot of a larger set of data, and this snapshot is exactly where something of interest is occurring. But, of course, by random variation there will always be these kinds of 'streaks' and 'droughts', or 'peaks' and 'valleys'.

Think of a sports announcer pointing that some person has 'made $4$ out of their last $5$ shots'.  Whenever you hear that, you can bet your house that they didn't make $4$ out of the last $4$, nor $5$ out of the last $6$, for otherwise the commentator would have said that. In other words yet, our brains naturally focus on 'interesting' clusters of data, and think that there is 'something going on there', when in fact it may well be just the result of random variation.

In fact, just to be perverse about it, you could have asked us: "just yesterday $1$ person of my team was selected for jury duty .. what are the chances of that: $1$ person over a period of $1$ day?!". Well, with $365$ days in the year, we have $57*365= 20805$ days, and so with $d$ being the probability of a person being selected during some day, we have that:

$$(1-d)^{20805} = 0.35$$

which solves to $d \approx 0.00005$

which is almost as unlikely as the earlier found probability of $2$ out of $2$ people getting selected for jury service during a $6$ month period. Moreover, the probability of getting $1$ or more out of $6$ people being selected during any day is:

$$1-(1-0.00005)^6 \approx 0.0003$$

which is *less* likely than $2$ out of $6$ people being selected during a $6$ month period! And yet, you would probably not feel as 'unlucky' as when some day $1$ person gets selected as you feel when $2$ people get selected over a period of $6$ months.

And finally, let's say that you have had this team for the past $5$ years, and during all that time, still only $2$ people have been selected (does that sound about right?) albeit just in the last $6$ months. Anyway, what is the chance of $2$ or more out of $6$ people being selected once or more times during a $5$ year period?

Well, if $y$ is the probability of being selected for jury service during some year, then the probability of never being asked for jury service over the course of your life is:

$$(1-y)^{57}=0.35$$

and so we get $y \approx 0.018$, i.e. you have a chance of about $1.8$% of being called for jury selection during any typical year.  OK, so this means that a person being asked for jury selection during a $5$  year period is:

$$1-(1-0.018)^5 \approx 0.087$$

meaning that $2$ or more out of $6$ people being asked for jury selection over a $5$ years period is:

$$1-(1-0.087)^6-6 \cdot (1-0.087)^5 \cdot 0.087 \approx 0.12$$

or about $12$ %.  So yes, if this is roughly your situation, you are unlucky ... but not 'strangely' unlucky.

Comment: Reading through your answer really had me smiling.  Thank you very much for answering my question and for adding the additional information and context.  Really interesting and very well explained; only wish I'd tried harder at school!

Comment: @InformationConstellation Glad you liked it! So how far off was I in guessing that these two selections were six months apart and the only two selections over a few years?

Answer (score 0):

A Poisson model seems appropriate here.  The expected number of people in a six-person group called for jury duty in a six-month period is
$$\lambda = \frac{0.35 \times 6 \times 6}{57 \times 12} =0.0184$$
Assuming the number of people called up follows a Poisson distribution, the probability that two or more people from the group are called for jury duty within a six-month period is
$$1 - e^{-\lambda} - \frac{\lambda}{1!} \; e^{-\lambda} = 0.000168$$